# Copying logs to network share location not working

Tags: powershell

Copying logs to network share location not working

I found the script below online and modified it to my needs. The script generates "logs.zip" to "SystemRoot\CCM\logs as expected but when I try to copy the "logs.zip" to a network share drive, it fails

I am using the command below to copy "logs.zip" to “\networkshare\software\Logs”

```
 $Computerlogshare = “\\networkshare\software\Logs” + $env:Computername
Copy-Item $env:SystemRoot\CCM\Logs\logs.zip -Destination $Computerlogshare -force 


# Script to run SetupDiag to troubleshoot Windows 10 Setup
# Download SetupDiag.exe from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=870142 and place in same directory as this script

# Get the CCM Logs location from registry
$LogLocation = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\Logging\@Global" -Name LogDirectory | Select -ExpandProperty LogDirectory
#$LogLocation = "$env:SystemRoot\CCM\Logs"

# Get the location we're running from (or use $PSScriptRoot)
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent



# Check that .Net 4.6 minimum is installed
If (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | ForEach-Object { $_ -ge 393295 })
{
    Try
    {
        Start-Process -FilePath "$ScriptPath\SetupDiag.exe" -ArgumentList "/Output:$LogLocation\SetupDiagResults.log" -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch
    {
       "[ERROR] There was an error starting SetupDiag.exe: $_" | Out-file -FilePath "$LogLocation\SetupDiagResults.log" -Force 
    }
}
Else
{
    "[ERROR] .Net Framework 4.6 is required to run SetupDiag.exe" | Out-file -FilePath "$LogLocation\SetupDiagResults.log" -Force
}

 $Computerlogshare = “\\networkshare\software\Logs” + $env:Computername
    Copy-Item $env:SystemRoot\CCM\Logs\logs.zip -Destination $Computerlogshare -force
```

Comment: Do you have access to network share from the network you are firing the script. Can you provide debug log or error message please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **DO NOT USE** curly 'smart-quotes' in code and replace them by straight ones.
Then, you are concatenating the path using `"\\networkshare\software\Logs"  + $env:Computername` which will result in `\\networkshare\software\LogsYourMachineName`.

My guess is you need to use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path), so the resulting destination path will become
`\\networkshare\software\Logs\YourMachineName`. 
You need to check if that path exists and if not create it before performing the `Copy-Item`.

Something like this:

```
$Computerlogshare = Join-Path -Path "\\networkshare\software\Logs" -ChildPath $env:Computername
if (!(Test-Path -Path $Computerlogshare -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $Computerlogshare -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
}
Copy-Item "$env:SystemRoot\CCM\Logs\logs.zip" -Destination $Computerlogshare -Force
```

Hope that helps

Comment: To clarify the quotes problem: `“\\networkshare\software\Logs”` has special opening and closing quotes that are not valid in Powershell and may have been copied in and out of a Word document or email. Word replaces [straight quotes](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html) in pasted text with slanted ones if you have smart-quotes enabled. The visual difference is subtle in Word and Notepad, but a little more obvious in the code font used by StackOverflow. Changing the text to read `"\\networkshare\software\Logs"` might fix your error.  Nice catch, @Theo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the path to:

```
$Computerlogshare = Join-Path -Path "Microsoft.Powershell.Core\FileSystem::\\networkshare\software\Logs" -ChildPath $env:Computername
```